# how to create dynamic List in google assistant rich responses?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I'm looking way to create dynamic list cards for the Google Assistant using node.js

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What @MaxWiederholt said. See [How Do I Ask A Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)